# Spring 3 and Rabbit MQ integration (not Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm having difficulty getting a Spring 3 application to integrate with RabbitMQ, in order to receive messages from a queue (I do not need to send messages).

Part of the challenge is much of the documentation now relates to Spring Boot. The [related Spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/) is helpful, but following the steps does not seem to work in my case. For instance, the guide includes the text:

> The message listener container and receiver beans are all you need to listen for messages.

So I have setup the listener container and receiver beans with the following code.

**Setting up message handler**

```
@Component
public class CustomMessageHandler {

    public void handleMessage(String text) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + text);
    }
}
```

**Setting up configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfig {

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setRoutingKey("queue-name");
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost("...host...");
        connectionFactory.setPort(5671);
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("...virtual host..");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("...username...");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("...password...");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter(CustomMessageHandler messageHandler) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(messageHandler, "handleMessage");
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                            MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setQueueNames("queue-name");
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately with this setup, the application will start up, but it never triggers the message handler. The queue it is trying to read from also has one message sitting in it, waiting to be consumed.

Any ideas on something that is missing, or appears misconfigured?

Comment: Spring Framework 3.x has been end of life for nearly 3 years. Which version of spring-rabbit are you trying to use and exactly which version of Spring?

Comment: @GaryRussell I certainly wish it was the latest Spring Boot and not Spring 3 :-) The current spring version is 3.2.18.RELEASE, and I'm using version 1.4.6.RELEASE of spring-rabbit and spring-amqp.

Comment: 1.4.6 was built against SF 4.1.7; I have no idea if it will work with Spring 3; the last version that was built against Spring 3.2 is 1.3.9 (nearly 5 years old). I have no idea if any of these will work with a modern RabbitMQ broker.

Comment: @GaryRussell thank you for the help. Using version 1.3.9 created other problems (due to its age), and I was pointed by someone else to use a RabbitMQ Java client library, which turned out to be a whole lot easier.

Comment: Yes, using the client directly is a solution (spring-rabbit uses the same client underneath). But you should really consider upgrading to a current version of Spring, regardless of whether you use the Spring for RabbitMQ projecr.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to some dependency management assistance from @GaryRussell, I was able to see that the version of spring-rabbit and spring-amqp were too recent. Using the older 1.3.9.RELEASE unfortunately proved to add additional challenges.

Some other assistance came in the form of using an actual RabbitMQ Java client. This option was much simpler to implement, and avoided the dependency problems. Ultimately I needed to include the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
    <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And then I simply followed their documentation on [creating a connection](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#connecting), and [consuming messages](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#consuming).

Voila, it works!

Comment: unfortunately, I am also dealing with such a problem.How did you solve the problem of method execution? Like in latest version of spring/spring boot, we can add a listener annotation on the method so that whenever a message arrives in that queue, that method gets auto executed. How did u do that using java rabbit client?

Comment: @SayedUzZaman did you look at the "creating a connection" and "consuming messages" links I provided? The first will show you how to setup a connection to RabbitMQ, and the second will show you how to receive/consume a message. These are with a Rabbit MQ client, not using the built-in Spring conventions for RabbitMQ. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I tried with them and pushing message+listening message is working. But the problem is, as I can not use annotations, I need to perform a manual method call with json data which will be extracted from the message. And this is a terrible idea as I have hundreads of methods and most of them have transaction enabled.